# When trying to connect to Queue Manager Using IBM MQ Explorer, I'm getting error as "Could not establish connection to the queue manager -reason 2538"

Tags: ibm-mq

could not establish a connection to the queue manager - reason 2538. (amq4059) severity: 10 (warning)
explanation: the attempt to connect to the queue manager failed. this could be because the queue manager is incorrectly configured to allow a connection from this system, or the connection has been broken. response: try the operation again. if the error persists, examine the problem determination information to see if any information has been recorded.

Please tell how do I resolve this.

Comment: 2538 means MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE (easy to find on Google). This means Explorer can't connect to that IP and Port.  Have you tried a telnet to that IP and port to validate if you can connect?  Have you checked with the MQ admin?  Is there a firewall between your machine and the MQ server?

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc But how do I telnet to that IP. Would I have to download an application in order to see if I can ping to that IP and Port No.?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc
My machine is not able to connect to the IP and Port. How do I fix it. I tried creating a rule on Windows Defender Firewall that allowed connection to all ports belonging to the IP address. This did not work, however.

Comment: Have you verified that MQ is listening on that IP and port?

Comment: How do I verify that, please suggest ? @JoshMc

Comment: Talk to the MQ admin.